# Add width and height to lazy loaded images

Tags: javascript, css, lazy-loading

I want to add height and width to each image on a page. I am using the JS code below. It is adding height and width (which can be seen on the console) but PageSpeed Insights keep on showing this error - *"Image elements do not have explicit width and height"*.

I am using `lazysizes` JS as well for that I need to replace src with data-src and add `lazyload` class. It seems to be adding height and width to an image does not work with lazy-loaded images. Because when I removed lazyload class, it works.

**Any solution to set the width and height to an image along with lazy load functionality?**

I can't do it manually as I have many images in a lot of articles.

```js
function addLazyloadClassToImages() {
    var images = document.querySelectorAll('img');
    for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        var image = images[i];
        if (!image.hasAttribute('height') && !image.hasAttribute('width')) {
            if (image.complete) {
                image.setAttribute('width', image.naturalWidth);
                image.setAttribute('height', image.naturalHeight);
            } else {
                image.addEventListener('load', function() {
                    this.setAttribute('width', this.naturalWidth);
                    this.setAttribute('height', this.naturalHeight);
                });
            }
        }
            
        image.setAttribute('data-src', image.getAttribute('src'));
        image.removeAttribute('src');
        image.classList.add('lazyload');
    }
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', addLazyloadClassToImages);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.3.2/lazysizes.min.js" integrity="sha512-q583ppKrCRc7N5O0n2nzUiJ+suUv7Et1JGels4bXOaMFQcamPk9HjdUknZuuFjBNs7tsMuadge5k9RzdmO+1GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<img alt="Sample Image" border="0" title="" src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hello-wording-comic-speech-bubble-pop-art-style_1150-39959.jpg">
```

Comment: The height and width of the content should be specified at the initial time, not after loading it. This is because page insight only considers the code that comes from the initial time, and ignores any changes made later. Might be it helps you.

Comment: But it works without lazyloaded images

Answer (score 0):

Afaik this is not how 'lazyloader' is used. It's designed to load a placeholder image and load the 'real image *after* the document is loaded.

So, the image in html should have a `src` with a placeholder image and a `data-src` attribute containing the `src` to load (lazy) afterwards.

If you want to set the with and height of the image(s), try adding a load event handler to them in the `DOMContentLoaded` handler. Something like:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', lazyWH);

function lazyWH() {
  const setWH = (image, origin) => {
    image.width = image.naturalWidth;
    image.height = image.naturalHeight;
    console.log(`${origin} => w: ${image.width}, h: ${image.height}`);
  };
  [...document.images]
    .forEach(image => {
      if (!image.complete) {
        return image.addEventListener(`load`, () => setWH(image, `load`));
      }
      
      return setWH(image, `complete`);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lazysizes/5.3.2/lazysizes.min.js" integrity="sha512-q583ppKrCRc7N5O0n2nzUiJ+suUv7Et1JGels4bXOaMFQcamPk9HjdUknZuuFjBNs7tsMuadge5k9RzdmO+1GQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>

<!-- note: image without src, which will be loaded lazy using its data-src attribute -->
<img alt="Sample Image" border="0" title="" 
  class="lazyload" 
  data-src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/hello-wording-comic-speech-bubble-pop-art-style_1150-39959.jpg">
<br>
  <img alt="Sample Image" border="0" title="" 
  class="lazyload" 
  data-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Lukmanierpass%2C_Passo_del_Lucomagno._20-09-2022._%28actm.%29_26.jpg/500px-Lukmanierpass%2C_Passo_del_Lucomagno._20-09-2022._%28actm.%29_26.jpg.jpg">
```

Comment: Thank you.. So you mean to say the following lines of code don't make sense as lazyload class and data-src should be in HTML only --         
image.setAttribute('data-src',image.getAttribute('src')); 
image.removeAttribute('src');
image.classList.add('lazyload');

Comment: But somehow PageSpeed Insights don't show errors "Defer loading" if I add lazyload class via JS

Comment: I don't know PageSpeed, so can't help you there, sorry